# In R, what is the fastest way to read and combine thousands of files into a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a directory of over 50,000 files that I need to combine in a single dataframe with the name of the file included as a column in the dataframe. Here is currently how I'm doing this:

```
files <- list.files(path="./")
df <- data.frame()
for (f in files){
  temp <- read.table(file = paste(resdir, f, sep = ""), header = TRUE, skip = 1)
  if (nrow(temp) == 0){
    print(paste(f,"has no rows!"))
    next()
  }
  temp$file <- f
  df <- rbind(df, temp)
}
```

The problem is that this is taking way too long; It's been running nearly 24 hours and seems to get slower with each additional file added. I would normally just concatenate all the files together and then load them in, but it's important that for each row in the dataframe I also have the filename information stored. I'm wondering if there is a significantly more efficient way to do this with lapply or something?

Comment: I like `data.table`, you can use `fread` which is very fast.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32867450/1412059

Comment: Also, the important part is merging the dataframes once and *not* incrementally -- using e.g. `data.table::rbindlist` or `dplyr::bind_rows`

Comment: Thanks! I've marked the question as duplicate to direct people to this answer.